# Extract just power features from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there a way to only download power features from OpenStreetMap in some sort of geodata?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Either by using [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) (see an [example for Berlin](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9SO) with the overpass turbo frontend) or by downloading a raw dataset and doing the filtering yourself using osmfilter or osmosis.

I suggesst to read about OSM's basic [elements](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) first. Also make sure to understand which [power tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:power) are in use.